# How I use python selenium for click Navigation Bar With Dropdown

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I want to click on "Page 1" for show list of sub menu
python code I used

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("nav/div/ul/li[2]/a").click()
```

website code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1
    <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

[Image of nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKmWj.jpg)

Comment: The thing is that you cannot click something that is not visible (I mean dropdown not showing their options). You'd take a look at Action Chains (http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains)

Comment: Try clicking the parent **dropdown** element first to show the child options (making it visible), then clicking the dropdown option you are after.

Comment: Have you performed clicked operation ? If no, Perform and share what is an actual error you are getting.

Comment: are you getting InvalidSelectorException?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your requirement is "**I want to click on "Page 1" for show list of sub menu**".

Instead of using absolute **xpath** , you can use **linkText**.

```
parent_page1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Page 1")))  
parent_page1.click()
```

if this **linkText** does not work out for you, you can use a relative xpath :

```
parent_page1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='dropdown-toggle' and contains(text(),'Page 1')]")))  
parent_page1.click()
```

Note that this code will click on Page 1 , if and only if it is clickable.

If it is a hover action then you can go ahead with **action chain**.

**Note :**  This is for parent Page1 . Not for child. and based on the xpath you have tried `nav/div/ul/li[2]/a`

Answer (score 0):

Your x-path is not correct. any x-path starts with **/ or //**. This may be the issue.

try with the x-path `//nav/div/ul/li[2]/a`

in code,

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//nav/div/ul/li[2]/a").click()
```

I guess, you are using [w3school bootstrap navigation bar](https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_dropdown&stacked=h). If yes, the page is inside frame, so first you need to switch to the frame as given below.

```
driver.switch_to_frame("iframeResult")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//nav/div/ul/li[2]/a").click()
```